# Count by average in multiple groups

Tags: mysql, database

I have data where each row represents one sentence in full review. Each row has a score (-1 to 1).

From that view I currently make 3 views where each has different group by, either by day, month or week and which aggregates average score for a review and
counts how many of them are positive and how many negative.

For example daily query from view:

```
SELECT
`review_score_view`.`review_date` AS `review_date`,
        COUNT(`review_score_view`.`review_id`) AS `review_count`,
        (AVG(`review_score_view`.`score`) * 100) AS `average_score`,
        SUM((CASE
            WHEN (`review_score_view`.`score` >= 0) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)) AS `positive_count`,
        SUM((CASE
            WHEN (`review_score_view`.`score` < 0) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)) AS `negative_count`
    FROM
        `review_score_view`
    GROUP BY `review_score_view`.`review_date`
```

And I get result like this:

```
| id  | review_date  | review_count |  average_score  | positive_count | negative_count |
|-----|--------------|--------------|-----------------|----------------|----------------|
| 521 |  2015-01-01  |      4       |     -25.0000    |      2         |      2         |
| 519 |  2015-01-07  |      1       |    -100.0000    |      0         |      1         |
| 518 |  2015-01-25  |      1       |     100.0000    |      1         |      0         |
| 516 |  2015-03-09  |      7       |      57.1429    |      6         |      1         |
| 515 |  2015-04-26  |      2       |     -50.0000    |      1         |      1         |
| 224 |  2015-06-01  |      68      |     -23.5294    |      40        |      28        |
| 222 |  2015-06-02  |      26      |    -100.0000    |      1         |      25        |
| 221 |  2015-06-03  |      41      |     -36.5854    |      19        |      22        |
| 220 |  2015-06-04  |      6       |     -50.0000    |      2         |      4         |
```

**Question**: How I can make another query from these view results based on average score. For each result (score categories), based on group by, either monthly, weekly or daily, I'd like to get a sum of these 5 results. Seems like an easy thing but I can't get my head around it.

```
SUM((CASE
    WHEN (average_score >= 75) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END)) AS very_positive,
SUM((CASE
    WHEN (average_score between 4 and 74) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END)) AS positive,
SUM((CASE
    WHEN (average_score between -5 and 5) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)) AS neutral,
SUM((CASE
    WHEN (average_score between -4 and -74) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)) AS negative,
SUM((CASE
    WHEN (average_score <= -75) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
END)) AS very_negative
```

Finally I would just plot the data. Quick example made in Excel:

[image: Pie]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  It looks like you want the results in rows, not columns.  This suggests `group by`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN average_score >= 75 THEN 'VeryPositive'
             WHEN average_score >= 4 THEN 'Positive'
             WHEN average_score >= -5 THEN 'Neutral'
             WHEN average_score >= -74 THEN 'Negative'
             ELSE 'VeryNegative'
        END) as ScoreGroup,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM dailyview v
GROUP BY ScoreGroup
ORDER BY ScoreGroup;
```

Note:  The `case` returns the first expression that matches, so the `between` is unnecessary.